# how to increase the count on scroll up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have to increase the count 1 on every scroll.like:

```
let scrollCount = 0;
//initially it would be 0 and after  every scroll up it should increase 1,
scrollCount++;
```

what is the function for increment count 1 on every scroll in react-native.

//below js code i know .. but for react-native getting confuse .

```
var scrollCount = 0;
           window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){

            if(e.wheelDelta<=0 && scrollCount<5){
            scrollCount++;
            }

          else if(e.wheelDelta>0 && scrollCount>1){
        scrollCount--;
        }
         document.querySelector('.number').innerHTML = scrollCount;
         });
```

Comment: View this [documentation API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscroll)

Answer (score 1):

```
object.onscroll = function(){
  //myScript
};
```

everytime it scrolls run your script

or add an event listener:

```
object.addEventListener("scroll", myScript);
```

It becomes like this:

```
var scrollCount = 0;
//object is your document. or any DOM element you would like to add
object.onscroll = function(){
  scrollCount++;
};
```

Comment: could you please elaborate little bit

Comment: I have to just increase my count value , that value i'll pass somewhere .

Comment: I have added some explanation.

Comment: I can write if(e.wheelDelta<=0 && scrollCount<countno){
                  scrollCount++;
                  }?

Comment: you don't need wheelDelta() here, because you are already capturing the scroll. add your script inside the function(){}

Comment: @AbhigyanGaurav can you vote my answer up and mark my answer correct to respect the communities guide lines please. people take from their time to answer questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You add an `onScroll` callback to your scrollable component.

For instance, if you have a `ScrollView`, you could do:

```
<ScrollView
  onScroll={this.handleScroll}
>
  <ComponentsWithinYourScrollView />
</ScrollView>
```

Depending on what you define as a scroll, you might want to only increment on every scroll action initiated by the user, and then you might want to do something like this:

```
<ScrollView
  onScrollBeginDrag={this.handleScrollStart}
>
  <ComponentsWithinYourScrollView />
</ScrollView>
```